# Does an actual vs. predicted value graph that looks like this have any particular meaning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I'm newer to ML and using sklearn, and I tried making a Regression enhanced random forest model following this stepwise process from a paper[Process for RERF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPlrJ.png)(. When I looked at the predicted vs. actual value graph, it kind of surprised me.
[Predicted vs. Actual graph for model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j86g8.png)
Is there any reason that this it seems to only be predicting a few constant values over the entire range of actual values, or is the model just lackluster for my purposes?

```
def train_models(x, y, lambda_val, m, s):
    lasso = Lasso(alpha=lambda_val, tol = 0.01)
    lasso.fit(x,y)
    residuals = y - np.dot(x, lasso.coef_)
    rf = RandomForestRegressor(min_samples_leaf=s, min_samples_split=m)
    rf.fit(x, residuals)
    return lasso, rf
```

```
class Rerf(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, lambda_val=None, m=None, s=None):
        self.lambda_val = lambda_val
        self.m = m
        self.s = s
    
    def fit(self, x, y):
        self.models = train_models(x=x, y=y, lambda_val=self.lambda_val, m = self.m, s = self.s)
        return self
    
    def predict(self, x):
        lasso = self.models[0]
        rf = self.models[1]
        base_pred = lasso.predict(x)
        residual_pred = rf.predict(x)
        y_pred = base_pred - residual_pred
        return y_pred
```

This is the initial model training function and a class based off the base estimator class of sklearn. Is it the model itself or something wrong with my code?

Comment: what the picture means is that your model is not very good ;-)
as for the code, why do you fit the RFR with residuals? that means it will try to match the value to a residual, as opposed to the true value. That does not seem right to me. You should be using rf.fit(x, y) like for the lasso model. Looking at the other picture, it seems your x should be something else, not the original x, if you need to fit the RFR with residuals.